# Carrots are for eyes as ________ are for ears

Tags: hearing, health, ear, procedure

Are there any vitamins or supplements or vegetables or procedures you know of that promote healthy and long-lasting ears?

I'm 25 and I want to continue in this business for many years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to a quick Google search...

Foods: Spinach, Potatoes, Broccoli, red meats, liver, Wheat germ, mango, kiwi, peanuts

Supplement: Alpha Lipoic Acid, Vitamin E

http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/387917/listen_up_foods_and_supplements_that.html (doesn't site sources)

As many of vitamin E's benefits are well documented, there are certain risks of ingestion of vitamin E that need to be described. For example, if you take beta blockers for cardio-vascular health, you should know that vitamin E can interfere with their action. Likewise, if you take coumadin, a "blood thinner" that is derived from warfarin, vitamin E supplementation may increase your risk of bleeding.

As with all meds and supplements, you really should check your doctor or pharmacist before you get started. THe University of Maryland has a good site describing vitamin E's benefits and risks:

http://www.umm.edu/altmed/articles/vitamin-e-000341.htm

Comment: Very nice!!!!!!

Comment: I knew there was a reason for my peanut addiction!

Answer (score 12):

Ear plugs. I guess you can't eat those though.....

or can you.....?

In all seriousness, the things you need to protect most in your ears are those tiny cilia like receptors deep down in the inner ear. Once one breaks, the frequencies that were dependent on that particular one drop significantly (if not entirely). Wearing earplugs in loud situations will preserve your hearing better than any particular food.

Comment: I guess I should be glad I never got invited to go to concerts as a kid? :-)

Comment: @Utopia - you and me both. lol

Comment: buy an SPL meter, take it to mixes, be disturbed

Comment: @tim prebble - there's a reason i've got those custom musician's earplugs. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about stuff we can consume to make our ears better but I've been reading about NIHD and stuff also check this out its pretty interesting and helpful, don't know if you've seen them before though.
[youtube]rRepnhXq33s[/youtube]
[youtube]ELgvDMTKyBE[/youtube]

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT drink tonic water... that means I had to quit drinking Gin and Tonic. Anything that contains quinine can cause Tinnitus. Same with smoking cigarettes.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea, thanks for the info. That should be taught at audio schools!
Not just hearsay I see.. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8143397

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the -ines.  Caffeine, nicotine, amphetamines, and, I was once told antihistamines.

Remember also that anything to do with the sinuses and glands can have an effect as well.  I have constant sinus trouble as a result of smoking shitty cigarettes and it totally messes with my Eustachian tubes (they run from the middle ear to the *checks wikipedia* nasopharynx).

Answer (score 0):

Omega 3 (Fish)

http://www.healthyhearing.com/content/articles/Hearing-loss/Treatments/47511-Hearing-loss-treatment-fish